# Unable to upload background picture using Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having issues trying to upload a background image to a page I'm building.

I'm using Bootstrap and I've created a div with a custom class. I want to add the background image using CSS however something is not working. Here's the code I wrote

```css
.homeinner {
  background-image: url("/.../../name.jpg");
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="homeinner">
</div>
```

Excuse me if the question may seem naive, I'm very new to coding and before writing here I've tried for hours different solutions.

The problem is not in the size or proportions of the image: it doesn't show at all :(

Could you please help me?

Comment: Deleted my last comment because I misunderstood the question. The part `/.../../name.jpg` is referring to a file named `name.jpg` 2 directories above the root folder of the domain. In order to you point to the image we need to know your folder structure nof your project.

Comment: Hi Johan, thanks for your reply. I may have used wrong words here, sorry. I'm not uploading an image, I'm creating the page from scratch and I want to add the image. sorry again.

Comment: yes, file called index.html is in the same directory (main one) of a folder named "assets", image path is --->  "assets/img/name.jpg"

Comment: Can you provide where in this structure your CSS file is located? Also, please update your question with the location of the files since they are needed to solve your problem.

Comment: assets/css/index.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS code you are referring to an image 2 steps above the root directory of the domain.

```
folder 1/  <-- This is the folder the image needs to be in with your current CSS
└─ folder 2/
   └─ domain/
```

Note that this is only possible if the files are served by an actual domain. Otherwise the leading `/` is referring to the root of the disk in the computer/server and the following `../../` would try to step up 2 directories (into the void or something, it's just not possible).

Based on the provided file structure, at the bottom of this answer, you should be able to just use a relative path (without the leading `/`) to the image itself from the CSS file. The following CSS should solve it

```css
.homeinner {
  background-image: url("../img/name.jpg");
}
```

This will step one directory up to the folder `assets` (the `../` part) and refer to the image `name.jpg` in folder `img`.

**Note**: This path does not have a leading slash `/`. This is why it's called a relative path because its origin is where the CSS file is located.

**Folder structure**:

```
root/
└─ assets/
   ├─ index.html
   ├─ img/
   |  └─ name.jpg
   └─ css/
      └─ index.css
```

Comment: YES it worked!! Thanks a lot Johan for your patience :)

Comment: Cheers, you're welcome. If you felt the answer helped you both understand and solve your issue I'd like to ask you to mark it as accepted. Normally I'd ask to mark the answer that helped you the most as accepted, but at the moment there's no other answers to your question.